# Compare Android String xml files

Tags: android, xml

I have two string xml for two different languages, I would like to know the different between those xml files.

For example, there is one xml for English,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Keep Accounts</string>
    <string name="insertNewOne">Insert Accounts</string>
    <string name="browseRecord">Browse Records</string>
    <string name="set">Setting</string>
</resources>
```

And another xml for other language,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Example</string>
    <string name="insertNewOne">Example</string>
    <string name="browseRecord">Example</string>
    <string name="dateNoColon">Example</string>
</resources>
```

We can see the difference is xml for English has element string `name="set"`, and the other has not. On the other hand, the xml file for other language has element string `name="dateNoColon"` but the xml for English has not.

In this case, I would like to know the English xml lacks the element string `name="dateNoColon"`, and other xml lacks the element string name="set".

Comment: no nedd to code or post example lol ,manually comparison is the only best way if you are dealing with string xml

Answer (score 2):

1. Android Studio has translations editor starting of 0.8.12 version. You can find there missing translation strings.

[image]

2. You can enable check for missing translations in Lint tool. There are "Missing translation" and "Extra translation" checks.

[image]

> **Extra translation**  If a string appears in a specific language translation file, but there is no corresponding string in the default locale, then this string is probably unused. (It's technically possible that your application is only intended to run in a specific locale, but it's still a good idea to provide a fallback.).
>
> **Incomplete translation**  If an application has more than one locale, then all the strings declared in one language should also be translated in all other languages.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose if the device is set to Other language, Android will look for title in the otherlanguage.xml file in value folder. But if no such string is included in that file, Android will fall back to the default, and will load title in English from the english.xml file.

For more detail go to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#using-framework

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small tool for that: resdiff.
Check it out! https://github.com/danijoo/resdiff

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting both files using some perl or bash script or something like that for example, using bash:

```
sort temp.txt -o temp.txt
```

and then look at the diff for example using `DiffMerge`it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Android Lint to find both incomplete translations i.e. strings missing in a language variant and extra translations i.e. strings introduced in a language variant but missing in the default locale.

In Android Studio you can run Lint (and some other analysis tools) with Analyze -> Inspect Code.